# How to build a contact list?

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list

How to build a sharepoint contact list (name, phone, email, pictures) that automatically syncs with user profile or active directory?

Also, can it be where when I input a account and it populates the rest of the data?

here is the fix. Result Query Options --- For Fixed Keyword Query = contentclass:spspeople --- For Append Text To Query = Department:"Sales&Order"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a People directory using the People Search without writing any code.

[How to: Create a Simple SharePoint 2010 People Directory](http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2011/05/how-to-create-a-simple-sharepoint-2010-people-directory/)

another way is use the infopath.

- Create the contacts list, and open in InfoPath
- Create a data connection to the User Profile web service
- Customize the form adding some text, a people picker and a button
- Create InfoPath rules that will populate the contact fields from the
  user fields in the User Profile store
- See more at: http://blogs.c5insight.com/Home/tabid/40/entryid/299/Auto-Populate-a-SharePoint-2010-Contact-List-from-User-Profile-Data.aspx#sthash.GjIXT1rg.dpuf

Comment: good article. How do I display result for a given department only? I dont need to display entire data set. This will be for Sales department and only their people will show up.

Comment: Looks like in 2013 you can only display a sub-set of result set. How is it done in 2010 without the refinement panel? http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/792761af-83df-4cf6-a34d-8989daf41f30/only-getting-a-subset-of-search-results-in-query

Comment: i am not sure about it, i have to check.

Comment: Will you let me know when you get a solution to this? Thank you very much.

Comment: I did this but only 2 people are showing instead of 50. Core result webpart under results query options for the Append Text To Query box i put this contentclass:spspeople and Department:"Sales&Order*"

Comment: here is the fix. Result Query Options
--- For Fixed Keyword Query = contentclass:spspeople --- For Append Text To Query = Department:"Sales&Order"